# one-liner assignment with exception raised on unexpected value

Tags: python-3.x, exception, variable-assignment, raise

Wanted to get some argument/input with the script and raise an exception when the value is not expected.

To simplify the scenario:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

foo = None or raise ValueError
```

But the following error was seen:

```
  File "./raise_on_assignment.py", line 3
    foo = None or raise ValueError
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know the error could be eliminated by breaking it into multi-lines, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

foo = None
if not foo:
    raise ValueError
```

But, is there a way to make it with a one-liner?

Comment: You should be able to put your two line solution on one line. You don't gain anything by having it on one line though. The first way fails because `raise ValueError` isn't an expression.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Could you give me an example on how to merge the multi-liner into a one-liner? All I want is to raise an exception when the variable `foo` is `None` (meaning the user didn't supply the value for the argument), within the same line.

Comment: Just take your two line code and remove the newline. Again though, you gain nothing by doing that. Smushed code is not necessarily better code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate True. That's why I want to know if there is some nicer way to do it, making it compact and easy to understand. Smushing is not my intent.

Comment: `if foo is None:<newline>raise ValueError` broken over two lines will be the most readable way. If you don't like how it looks, you could wrap that in a function. Something like `def assert_truthy(val):<newline>if val is None:<newline>raise ValueError(f"The value was None!")`. Then you'd just do `assert_truthy(foo)` if you want a one-line solution. (Note that `<newline>` is just me indicating a newline. That is not valid Python syntax).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, but my intention is to merge `assert` with the assignment (or the param reading operation) into one line. Could it be possibly done?

Answer (score 1):

You could get it in 2 lines, for example like this:

```
foo = None
if foo != None: raise ValueError
```

I dont think you can define a new value, check an if condition, and raise a ValueError in one line, i still might be wrong.

You should maybe look for ternary operators in python.